# How does jQuery's synchronous AJAX request work?

Tags: asynchronous, jquery

Does `jQuery.ajax({async: false})` still use the XMLHttpRequest object?

If so, how is the request synchronous?

Is there just some mechanism inside the function definition that allows the asynchronous request put out by the XHR to be wrapped in a synchronous wrapper?

I ask because I want to wrap asynchronous function calls into a synchronous wrapper.

**EDIT**:

I want to do this for dependencies. I need to not run anything more until all the external dependency scripts are loaded, however, I'd rather not load each of the files synchronously.

Basically, I want this:

```
require(['lib1.js','lib2.js'])

Library1Function();
Library2Function();
```

To load lib1 and lib2 at the same time, but block until both are loaded.

I know I could do this with a callback, however that doesn't work if the files I'm including also have dependencies included in the same way.

**EDITx2**

Reason why callbacks don't work:

```
# lib2.js
window.Library2Function = function(input) {
  alert(input);
}

# lib1.js
require('lib2.js', function() {
  window.Library1Function = function() {
    window.Library2Function('Hi there');
  }
});

# main.js
require('lib1.js', function() {
  window.Library1Function();
});
```

The problem is that, in main.js, that callback will get sent off once lib1.js is loaded and run.
The problem is, `Library2Function` isn't actually defined until lib2.js is loaded, which happens *after* lib1.js is parsed.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by 'synchronous wrapper' and why you need one?

Comment: On your edit: why don't callbacks work?  Can you clarify a bit more?

Comment: Your problem seems to be that you're calling `eval` *after* you call the callback.  Call `eval` first so the script runs (which will block on the `require` inside the `require`'d script) and then call the callback when everything is finished.

Comment: The problem is that it _won't_ block on the require inside the require'd script unless require is actually a blocking script. I can easily make this system work if I make require block, but I want to be able to include multiple dependencies for a single script simultaneously. This way the load time will be closer to `log(n)` than to `n`, as it just has to branch out the tree, instead of going through linearly.

Comment: @Jamie Wong, Ah, you're right.  I really forgot what I did to make my script loader (which uses callbacks) handle this problem.  (And sadly, I don't have access to the script loader's code anymore.)

Comment: My current plan is as follows: Instead of making the require calls real javascript functions, I'll put them in the comments like `//@require 'lib.js'`. Then, everytime I go fetch a script, I'll parse the headers but won't actually `eval` it until all the dependencies are met.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does `jQuery.ajax({async: false})` still use the `XMLHttpRequest` object?

Yes.

[`XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/XMLHttpRequest#open()) accepts `async` as its third parameter.  If it's true (default), the request is asynchronous.  Otherwise, it's synchronous.

> I ask because I want to wrap asynchronous function calls into a synchronous wrapper.

Why do you want to do this?  This will most likely result in more problems than it "fixes".

Comment: See edit - I might accept your answer and move that to another question though.