# Cannot make unload event fire in Firefox 4

Tags: ajax, firefox, onunload

I have run **ajax-calls on the unload event** for about a year.
It has generally worked in FF and IE but not to 100%, I cannot say when it has failed.
I register the event by writing in the bodytag:
    onunload="...."
I got error messages in FF4 since the unload event also wanted to write in a div-tag of the page that just had unloaded. Fixed this by making the ajax-routine write nothing if the id of the target div is 'dummy'
I am no expert on AJAX, but the following code has worked:
http://yorabbit.info/e-dog.info/tmp/ajax_ex.php  (the link is a text-page)
(You call ajaxfunction2 with the following arguments: filename, queryString for PHP, string to show in target div during update, name of target div)

I don't get any error messages in the FF error console and IE9 works. **Is there any way I can make it work in FF too??** I have just started trying FF4, but my impression is that it works less well than in FF3.

Thanks.

(I am on a trip and ay not have the possibility to reply immediately, but I really appreciate suggestions and will reply in due course)

EDIT:
I had bettter add this:
**The AJAX-call I make on unload does only send some data (how long time the user stayed on the page) to the PHP-MySQL server**

Comment: Are the Ajax calls you make synchronous ones?

Comment: I apologize, I do not know what that is? (I just thought AJAX was asyncroneous, since it has it in the name.) I will try to look it up. But I just execute the routine in this link http://yorabbit.info/e-dog.info/tmp/ajax_ex.php on page unload.

Comment: I don't know what is happening here, but Firefox 4 has made notable changes to how unloading works: For example, if you do an `alert()` during a link click event, it will no longer freeze the page, but load the new location anyway. Maybe this is something similar - but you are never guaranteed for the Ajax call to finish if it is not asynchronous

Comment: The answer to this question shows how to do synchronous calls: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481970/how-does-jquerys-synchronous-ajax-request-work - but it could be that Firefox overrides these too in version 4, you'd have to try out.

Comment: Thank you Pekka. You pointed at the difference between synchronous and asynchronous AJAX calls. I must read up on this matter. It seems to be highly relevant here. I must create a simpler test environment. But if I manage to create asynchronous calls (I just send data to the PHP (MySQL) server - how long time the user stayed on the page) then it would work?

Comment: @ycc Doing synchronous calls is the accepted way to do this in an onunload event. I don't know how FF4 is going to behave though - as said, they seem to have changed a lot in that field. But if this is to detect how long a user stayed on a page, why not do a normal Ajax call every 30 seconds or so?

Comment: I do that too :) But as I am beginning to understand, using the unload event is not 100% reliable so maybe I should scrap that part. The repeated 30 seconds call works fine. The onunload worked about 50-70 % of the time, but I have not analyzed when. The little I have tried it seems to wrk in IE9. Thanks Pekka, you point at things I need to know.

Comment: @ycc you're welcome. I'll write up an answer from these  comments.

Comment: I made a typo in the third comment: It has to ready *synchronous*, not *asynchronous*. Ajax calls are of course a-synchronous by default. Sorry

Comment: But the conclusion is this: _There is no 100% safe method to reach the unload event._  Is that correct?

Comment: @ycc the unload event is basically safe, and if you do a blocking (synchronous) Ajax call in it, it should be guaranteed to work - at least it has been until now, I don't know whether Firefox 4 changes this in any way. However, because of the security implications - this is a way to keep a user on a specific page for a long time by not sending a response to the Ajax call, and waiting for the browser to time out - I expect this behaviour may be abolished by future browser versions. I wouldn't rely too much on it. In your case, I would stick with the 30-second interval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what is happening here, but Firefox 4 has made notable changes to how unloading works: For example, if you do an alert() during a link click event, it will no longer freeze the page, but load the new location anyway. Maybe this is something similar.

However, you are never guaranteed for the Ajax call to finish if it is not synchronous in any browser *anyway* - the request may or may not come back with a response until the page has been closed. Whether this works will be down to chance, and the user's network speed.

Try using a synchronous request first, as outlined here: [How does jQuery's synchronous AJAX request work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481970/how-does-jquerys-synchronous-ajax-request-work)

this will usually guarantee that the request comes back. However, use it *very* sparingly - blocking behaviour at page unload can be very annoying for the user, and even freeze the browser.

Comment: Thank you. But since I do nothing in the browser/client on unload I thought it would still work? I only send data to the PHP/MySQL server on unload. But I realize I know too little here and must try and create a simpler test-environment to see what happens. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @ycc the thing is, if you do a normal Ajax request, you have no guarantee that it will reach the server before the page unloads. That's where  your 50-70% success rate comes from. Maybe Firefox 4 now unloads the page so quickly that it *never* works. If you want a guaranteed result, you need to block the browser until the response comes back (= synchronous call) but that can be a big annoyance for the user, because it delays loading the new page.

Comment: Thanks Pekka, you have already put me several steps forward. I understand most of what you say. So the 50-70% success rate comes from some kind of competition between the AJAX call and some other general "unload" mechanism that will not allow sending the AJAX call at all? Is this "competition" within the browser or will there be an "unload" message sent over the internet to the server, that might cancel the AJAX request? (OK maybe not so easy to answer, sorry if question is not logical)

Comment: @ycc the Ajax request is asynchronous. It runs *alongside* the script, which is heading for "death" (i.e., unloading). If the request is fast enough, it manages to contact the server before the page gets unloaded. If it's not, the unload event will not wait for it. That's  the gist of it

Comment: sorry Pekka, but your answer feels wrong, find solution below, you can hijack the leaving link, run a synchronous ajax (so the browser waits) call and redirect in success case

Comment: that's why I said 'feels' wrong - a) he said it worked for a year and then stopped working with a new browser version -> that's why I recommend jQuery, so you don't have to take care of those problems yourself b) i suggest to move away from the unload event at all, i prefer to use events that are actually triggered by users, find it to be a cleaner (and more polite) approach

Comment: @ezmilhouse re a) you're right in general, but this specific thing probably has to do with the way browsers handle the onunload event. If that is changed in a new browser version for security reasons, jQuery won't be able to influence it. Still, using a framework for this stuff is always  good advice.  b) I misunderstood that about your suggestion, that's indeed a much better approach (even though it won't catch every close event).

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use jQuery instead of keeping track of browser changes yourself.

**Solution:**
Find working sample here: [http://jsfiddle.net/ezmilhouse/4PMcc/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/ezmilhouse/4PMcc/2/)

Assuming that your internal links are set relatively, and your external links therefore set starting with 'http':

```
<a href="http://google.com">Leave ...</a>
<a href="/home.html">Stay ...</a>
```

You could hijack 'a' tags via jQuery events and ask the user to confirm the leaving (in case of external links). In 'ok' case you kick off your 'onleave' ajax call (async=true) and redirect user to external link:

```
$('a').live('click', function(event){

    // cache link
    var link = $(this).attr('href');

    // check if external link (assuming that internal links are relative)
    if (link.substr(0,4) === "http") {

        // prevent default a tag event
        event.preventDefault();

        // popup confirm message
        var reply = confirm('Do you really want to leave?');
        if (reply) {

            var url = 'http:mydomain.com/ajax.php';
            var data = {'foo': 'bar', 'fee':'bo'};

            // kick off your 'onleave' ajax call
            // forced to be synchronous
            $.ajax({ 
                type: "POST",
                async: false,
                url: url,
                data: data,
                success: function( data ) { 

                   // ok case: leave page, cached link
                   window.location.href = link;

                }
            });

        }

        return false;

    }

});
```

Comment: The OP is making an Ajax request in the event, using jQuery won't change that

Comment: Is it possible that the jQuery makes the AJAX call in another way, in a way that works better in FF4 than mine do? In that case I might try it? (my call: http://yorabbit.info/e-dog.info/tmp/ajax_ex.php I got this by cutting, pasting and modifying. Apologize for not having appropriate credits.)

Comment: +1 for a well worked out suggestion, although I think it will not be sufficient for the OP's case because he wants to track the time spent on the page, and will need to catch *all* unload events - closing the browser ends looking at the page, too. Still, this can be useful in many scenarios - bearing in mind that blocking Ajax calls should be used very carefully

Comment: Thanks both of you for sharing. I hope I get time to try the jQuery too. So far I have found it interesting to try to understand how the JS-code itself works and used jQuery sparingly. But I'm sure it is a good framework. What I must read up on are the synchronous AJAX calls. I don't think I have used them before. Thanks for pointing out their existence.